# org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException i spring-data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t1.* FROM western_en AS t1 " +
        "JOIN (SELECT id FROM western_en " +
        "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) as t2 ON t1.id=t2.id", nativeQuery = true)
List<WesternEs> findRandom();
```

but I have this error runnning the query:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [com.models.WesternEs]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:294)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:185)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToObjectConverter.convert(ArrayToObjectConverter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_western_es")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
@Slf4j
public class WesternEs implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to see what does the query returns on an SQL console?

After trying that, see if the data that output from the query is the same as the `WesternEs` entity fields (and if the types of the data could be the "same").

But this looks like the column `id` is returning as a Long and the `WesternEs` entity `id` is probably not a `Long`??

If after this you couldn't solve it, could you provide more information about `WesternEs` entity?